# Imessage circles on groupchat replication

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

this question might be unique to other questions on stackoverflow, but I am wondering how I could make the overlapping circles in iMessage when messaging with multiple users. Here is an example:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsSp4.jpg)

I was thinking of using a collection view, but I am not sure how to overlap them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Bezier Paths](https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/) or just use the great [Macaw](https://github.com/exyte/Macaw) framework!